# Regex won't consider an optional group even if it's there

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use RegExp in TS to capture the following lines

```
таб. 10мг/10мг х 30
x 30
```

I'm using this regex

```
^.*?(капс|капли|таб|амп|супп|фл|мазь|гель|паста|кап|крем)?(?:(?:((\d+)(?:,\d+)?)\s?(мл|л|мг|г))(?:\/((\d+)(?:,\d+)?)\s?(мл|л|мг|г))?).*?(?:(?:x|х)\s*(\d+))?$
```

And the problem is that if I use a `?` before the last `.*?` it doesn't catch all of the numbers in the first line, and if I don't, it naturally doesn't capture the second line.

Is there anything I'm missing? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't allow `.` and spaces after the group with all the alternatives that should match `таб`. Try this:

```
^.*?(?:(капс|капли|таб|амп|супп|фл|мазь|гель|паста|кап|крем)\.\s+)?(?:(?:((\d+)(?:,\d+)?)\s?(мл|л|мг|г))(?:\/((\d+)(?:,\d+)?)\s?(мл|л|мг|г))?).*?(?:(?:x|х)\s*(\d+))?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qxg6U9/1)